# Reset MeasurementIndex to 0 in Vector CANoe?

Tags: capl, canoe

Is there a way to reset the MeasurementIndex of a CANoe Simulation to 0?

I'm currently working on a `myCANoe.cfg` simulation that was saved multiple times. I'm creating log files with the structure `myCANoe_{MeasurementIndex}.blf` and `MeasurementIndex = 800` right now. I'd like to tweak the text in `myCANoe.cfg` to reset it to zero. So far, searching for the string was not effective, nor it was changing the preview text `myCANoe_800.blf` in `myCANoe.cfg`. Can we achive this result somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also change it in File > Options > General
[image: Options]

Answer (score 1):

Turns out there is a simple way. Please be sure to have a back-up plan in case the following edits go south. You'll need to manually edit the `myCANoe.cfg` file, possibly resulting in complete corruption of the simulation. I was able to achieve the result with the following:

1. Note the current measurement index (e.g. 800)
2. Delete myCANoe.stcfg compiled file
3. Open the simulation
4. Check current measurement index again and close simulation
5. Delete myCANoe.stcfg again
6. edit myCANoe.cfg with a text editor
7. Search for the measurement index value (800). I found two results: one on row 609, one with the format `<VFileName V7 QL> 1 "myCANoe_800.blf"`
8. Edit both to 0 and 000, respectively. Save
9. Open the CANoe configuration, My measurement index was re-set.